# Delete set of records if pattern found

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, sed, vim

It may be duplicate but don't flag this,Guys i am performing manual tasks doing some work *not able to get exact solution* so far deleted 5000 lines out 45000,trying to make as simple as possible

```
ORDER ALPHA

Facility: 201  ZZZ        COUNTRY
Wrong Trace:       Kotak: NA       Soak: NA        NOUN: XP

                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O
                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O   LAM
AMO ORDER #   P/P R  O  L  H  S  C  N  D  K  M  D  D  C  N   LAM uii ii oo
--- --------  --- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  --- --- -- --

    BZ90rty   K/K AA AA AA NA XP AP NA NA NA NA NA NA AP AP  OOL XP  IP N
a      ZX     A/A WD WD WD NA WD WD NA NA NA NA NA NA WD WD  OOL WD  IP Y
ORDER BURY

Facility: 201  ZZZ        COUNTRY
Wrong Trace:       Kotak: NA       Soak: NA        NOUN: XP

                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O
                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O   LAM
AMO ORDER #   P/P R  O  L  H  S  C  N  D  K  M  D  D  C  N   LAM uii ii oo
--- --------  --- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  --- --- -- --

    BZ903901  A/A AA AA AA NA XP AP NA NA NA NA NA NA AP AP  OOL XP  IP N
a      ZX     A/A WD WD WD NA WD WD NA NA NA NA NA NA WD WD  OOL WD  IP Y

ORDER ALUIO

Facility: 201  ZZZ        COUNTRY
Wrong Trace:       Kotak: NA       PAT: NA        NOUN: AP

                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O
                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O   LAM
AMO ORDER #   P/P R  O  L  H  S  C  N  D  K  M  D  D  C  N   LAM uii ii oo
--- --------  --- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  --- --- -- --

    BZ903901  U/U AA AA AA NA XP AP NA NA NA NA NA NA AP AP  OOL XP  IP N
a      ZX     Y/Y WD WD WD NA WD WD NA NA NA NA NA NA WD WD  OOL WD  IP Y
ORDER AL123  ...cont....
```

If `NOUN :XP` with `A/A` && `K/K` is found delete these type of records from file

*Why most of scripts are failing because condition like this( if NOUN :AP and A/A && K/K is there) it is displaying that record too... or conditions like these(if NOUN :XP with A/Z && K/Z) it is displaying that record too...and i need to delete these records not keep them.*

output---->

```
ORDER ALPHA
Facility: 201  ZZZ        COUNTRY
Wrong Trace:       Kotak: NA       Soak: NA        NOUN: XP

                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O
                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O   LAM
AMO ORDER #   P/P R  O  L  H  S  C  N  D  K  M  D  D  C  N   LAM uii ii oo
--- --------  --- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  --- --- -- --

    BZ90rty   K/K AA AA AA NA XP AP NA NA NA NA NA NA AP AP  OOL XP  IP N
a      ZX     A/A WD WD WD NA WD WD NA NA NA NA NA NA WD WD  OOL WD  IP Y
```

Note `NOUN [small space is there]:XP`, rows and column are dynamic.

Comment: I would use awk. what have you tried?

Comment: So far no luck sed '
    /^Block/! D
    :1
    N
    $!{
       /\n\s*KEY/! b1
    }
    \%SAM.*D/D.*D/D\|SAM.*X/Y.*Z/Z%! d
    ' log. Printing odd values

Comment: I have made question very clear you can provide in awk,  but can it work normal Linux 2.6.32-642.6.el6.x86_64

Comment: Do all the order records have 4 lines?

Comment: No order have dynamic lines sometime they may extend or decrease according to user details.

Comment: Re: 'It may be duplicate but don't flag this' -- a duplicate is a duplicate; don't worry about it; your Q wouldn't be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
    function print_record() {
        if (record ~ /Stack :IR/ && record ~ /F\/F/ && record ~ /X\/X/) return
        printf "%s", record
    }
    tolower($1) == "order" {if (NR > 1) print_record(); record = ""}
    {record = record $0 ORS}
    END {print_record()}
' file
```

---

Given your edit, all that needs to change is this:

```
function print_record() {
    if (record ~ /NOUN: XP/ && record ~ /A\/A/ && record ~ /K\/K/)
        printf "%s", record
}
```

Comment: Sir it is showing negative results it is showing Stack :RS , if x/x and f/f fall under that RS record.please delete the records.

Comment: Your question says to delete if ":IR" and "F/F" and "X/X". If that's not the case, then negate the if condition: `if ( !( ...) ) return `

Comment: No sir it is not working I did diff and checked and manually checked.

Comment: this does not update the file, it outputs results to stdout. If you need to update the file, do this: `awk '...' file > tmpfile && mv tmpfile file`

Comment: No I tried it's not working sir I am finding this task mission impossible I asked 4 times but not luck.

Comment: "not working" is the most useless problem description. You should show your input file and the output, and describe how the output differs from what you want.

Comment: One more thing why we cannot delete the records if match is found.why redirecting.

Comment: Production logs cannot expose but why cannot if script work on sample log it should on that log it's not much difference.

Comment: If you ask precisely and with a good description, the chances to have a correct answer will improve.
The script that @glenn-jackman did is great and can do what you asked for. Please, be more precise. Put an example of the input (change the values to not expose your production) and the desired output.
Another very useful tip is to give more details about what is the problem istead of just "not working"...

Comment: Shortly in few minutes I will redit my question and expose clone of the logs